# how do I paste multiple lines of code into the chat (in the chatroom)?

Tags: support, chat

The only way I know to copy multi lines of code into the chat is to copy one line by one line and for each line inserting a ` at the start and at the end.

I have searched informations all over the site but was not successfull.

Answer (score 6):

Simply paste the code by itself into the comment box.
you should see a new button appear to the right: **fixed font**

-- click that and it should format your comment as code.

[image]

Tested with Chrome/Windows

(informations coming from the chat, Mr.Wizard)

I suggest to play with this feature in the [sandbox chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox) : it works too.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Ctrl+K works, too.